# Grabbing pixels from 8bit greyscale image

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I have 8 bit greyscale image. I need to grab pixels from it, to byte array. So one pixel=1byte in array, but grabber always grabs pixel as integer(4bytes). Do you kknow how to tell him to grab one pixel as one byte ?

Comment: What is `grabber`? Do you use a library or is it your own code?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this question requires more clarification, but a 4-byte grayscale pixel will always be in the form 0x00ABABAB.  Since AB are the same in the last 3 bytes, you can simply right shift off the bits that you need.

Comment: Hi jkschneider,

thank you for your prompt and useful answer :).

Comment: No one had given this +1. Deserves it.